# Replacing values in a list

Tags: python

Basically, I'm trying to create a program that will replace the values of diceList with a random integer between 1 and 6 wherever my indexList has a 1 in it. This is what I have so far:

```
import random
def replaceValues(diceList, indexList):
    newList = diceList
    for i in indexList:
        if indexList == 1:
            newList[i] = random.randint(1,6)
        return newList
```

I'm executing `replaceValues([1,2,3,4,5], [0,1,0,1,0])` and what I should get is `[1,x,3,x,5]` where x should be a random number between 1 and 6. The problem is it currently returns [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: You mean `between 2 and 6`, right?

Comment: ...annnd what is the problem?

Comment: No I meant 1 and 6 but I see the error I made and right now it just returns the list [1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 2):

Is `indexList` a `list`? If so, what does a `list == 1` mean?

```
if indexList == 1:
    newList[i] = random.randint(1,6)
```

Did you perhaps mean `i == 1` ?

Edit:

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
def replaceValues(diceList, indexList):
    newList = diceList
    if len(diceList) == len(indexList):
        for pos in range(0, len(indexList)):
            if indexList[pos] == 1:
                newList[pos] = random.randint(0,6)
        return newList
```

Comment: yes indexList is a list of zeros and ones. Wherever there is a "1", then it should replace the diceList with a random number at the "1"

Comment: Sorry, I have a better understanding of what you want now. Updated my post.