# Replacing values in a list with certain words

Tags: python

I want to replace a value in a list with certain words.

```
acts = []

act = input('Acts: ')
acts.append(act.split())

change = input('Change: ')
while change:
  if 'Scratch' in change:
```

So basically, I have a list of acts, and if the command (change) contains the word scratch, then I replace the act in the list with the word 'scratch', and I don't want the order of the values to change.

How would I replace the 2nd word of the command (change) with the word scratch in the list?

Example:

```
Acts: Cynthia Edward Princess Natasha Shehabi Back-To-Front
Change: Scratch Natasha
Change: Scratch Edward
Change: 
Cynthia -SCRATCHED- Princess -SCRATCHED- Shehabi Back-To-Front
```

Comment: can you give us example acts, and example command? because your question isn't as clear.

Comment: Just added an example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing values in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109019/replacing-values-in-a-list)

Comment: marking as possible duplicate since it shares the exact title as a previous question

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the input to 'Change' will contain exactly 2 words separated by a space.

```
acts = input('Acts: ').split()

while True:
    change = input('Change: ')
    if not change:
        break

    _to, _from = change.split()

    for i, act in enumerate(acts):
        if act == _from:
            acts[i] = _to

print(' '.join(acts))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
acts = ['Cynthia', 'Edward', 'Princess', 'Natasha', 'Shehabi' ,'Back-To-Front']
print "Acts: {}".format(" ".join(acts))
change = raw_input('Change: ')
while (change.strip() != ''):
    if 'Scratch' in change:
        act = change.replace('Scratch','').strip()
        if act in acts:
            acts[acts.index(act)] = '-SCRATCHED-'
    change = raw_input('Change: ')
print " ".join(acts)
```